# Determining first and last UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with 3 sections, each returning for numberOfRows the count in 3 separate arrays. In my cellForRow, I need to be able to detect which cell is the first cell in the table and which is the last.

The tricky part is that sometimes a section can return a count of 0 for number of rows, so I'm having a hard time figuring this out. All I'm trying to do is set two flags: `isTopCell` and `isBottomCell`. Any ideas?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section==0)
        return [array1 count];
    else if(section==1)
        return [array2 count];
    else return [array3 count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 if(/*something, what I'm trying to figure out*/)
      isTopCell=YES;
 if(/*something, what I'm trying to figure out*/)
      isBottomCell=YES;
}
```

Edit: Let me clarify. The 3 sections are unified. I want to determine the overall top and bottom cell. if(indexPath.row==0) will return true for 3 sections. I need only 1 winner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
int index = indexPath.row;
if (indexPath.section > 0) index += [array1 count];
if (indexPath.section > 1) index += [array2 count];

if (index == 0) // Top row

if (index == [array1 count] + [array2 count] + [array3 count] - 1) // Bottom row
```

Comment: What if section 0 returns count of 0? This would break

Comment: @mohabitar Thanks, this should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing tricky about it. Here it is for an arbitrary number of sections:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger totalIndex = indexPath.row;
    NSInteger numberOfSections = [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView];
    NSInteger totalNumberOfRows = 0;

    for (NSInteger currentSection = 0; currentSection < numberOfSections; currentSection ++) {
        NSInteger rowsInSection = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:currentSection];
        totalNumberOfRows += rowsInSection;
        if (currentSection < indexPath.section) totalIndex += rowsInSection;
    }

    BOOL isTopCell = (totalIndex == 0);
    BOOL isBottomCell = (totalIndex == totalNumberOfRows);
}
```

Comment: But what if the section is 1 and the row is 0? Then it's not a top cell, its a mid cell

Comment: Oh, you want the top and bottom rows in the **table**. Then it's even *less* tricky.

Comment: This still wouldn't work. the topCell doesn't necessarily have to be in section 0. It could be section 2 if both section 0 and 1 return 0 rows..

Comment: Generalized to arbitrary number of sections.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    BOOl isTopCell = NO;
    BOOl isBottomCell = NO;

    int totalNumberOfCells = [array1 count] + [array2 count] + [array3 count];

    int cellOverallPosition = 0;

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0: { cellOverallPosition = indexPath.row; } break;
        case 1: { cellOverallPosition = indexPath.row + [array1 count]; } break;
        case 2: { cellOverallPosition = indexPath.row + [array1 count] + [array2 count]; } break;
    }

    if (cellOverallPosition == 1) { isTopCell = YES; }

    if (cellOverallPosition == totalNumberOfCells) { isBottomCell = YES; }

    //Other cell stuff follows

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is not to rely on your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as it only runs for the cells that are visible on screen. I'd suggest figuring things out in your `numberOfSectionsInTableView` instead. Here's code that should work. First lets add two index paths to your `.h` file:

```
@interface MyTable : UITableViewController {
    ...
    NSIndexPath *ip_top;
    NSIndexPath *ip_bottom;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath *ip_top;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath *ip_bottom;
```

And in your `.m` file:

```
...
@implementation MyTable

@synthesize ip_top;
@synthesize ip_bottom;
```

and of course we need to release these in the `dealloc`:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [ip_top release];
    [ip_bottom release];
}
```

Now let's get the the meat and bones of the logic. First we'll modify `numberOfSectionsInTableView` since it runs once every time the table is loaded/reloaded:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tv {
    NSLog(@"Getting number of sections");
    self.ip_top = self.ip_bottom = nil;
    int i_numSections = 3;
    int i_numRows;
    for (int i=0; i<i_numSections; i++) {
        i_numRows = [self tableView:tv numberOfRowsInSection:i];
        NSLog(@"num_rows:%d for section:%d",i_numRows,i);
        if (i_numRows > 0) {
            if (!ip_top) {
                self.ip_top = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:i];
            }
            self.ip_bottom = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i_numRows-1 inSection:i];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"top:%@ bottom:%@",ip_top,ip_bottom);

    return i_numSections;
}
```

Notice that it will find the first section that has more than 1 row in it and point `ip_top` to that otherwise `ip_top` will be `nil`. Similar logic for `ip_bottom` which will point to the last row. Now we need to check for this in our `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ...

    if ([indexPath compare:ip_top] == NSOrderedSame) {
        NSLog(@"top cell section:%d row:%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row);
    }
    if ([indexPath compare:ip_bottom] == NSOrderedSame) {
        NSLog(@"bottom cell section:%d row:%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row);
    }

    ...
}
```

Make sense? Go get em!

Answer (score 0):

for the first

```
if(indexPath.row == 0)
```

for the last

```
if(indexPath.row == sectionarray.count - 1)
```

and with sectionarray i mean of course your arrays 1-3
you will have to determine which to use with

```
indexPath.section
```

that will return the values 0,1,2 for you 3 sections =)

alternatively you can get the count like that

```
[self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for any table view - an arbitrary number of sections and an arbitrary number of rows in each section. It also handles the case of just having one row (by detecting the row as both the top and the bottom row). Just add it to the top of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
BOOL isTop = NO;
BOOL isBottom = NO;
int sections = [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView];
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
  // Could be first
  isTop = YES;
  for (int i = indexPath.section-1; i>=0; i--) {
    if ([self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i] > 0) {
      // Non-empty section above this one, so not first.
      isTop = NO;
      break;
    }
  }
}
if (indexPath.row == [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1) {
  // Could be last
  isBottom = YES;
  for (int i = indexPath.section + 1; i < sections; i++) {
    if ([self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i] > 0) {
      // Non-empty section below this one, so not last.
      isBottom = NO;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what i have done in my project is that i have set the images of 1 and last cell of the table view which will be different from the rest of the cells

i use the followingg code

```
//
    // Set the background and selected background images for the text.
    // Since we will round the corners at the top and bottom of sections, we
    // need to conditionally choose the images based on the row index and the
    // number of rows in the section.
    //
    UIImage *rowBackground;
    UIImage *selectionBackground;
    NSInteger sectionRows = [aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    if (row == 0 && row == sectionRows - 1)
    {
        rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topAndBottomRow.png"];
        selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topAndBottomRowSelected.png"];
    }
    else if (row == 0)
    {
        rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topRow.png"];
        selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topRowSelected.png"];
    }
    else if (row == sectionRows - 1)
    {
        rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomRow.png"];
        selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomRowSelected.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"middleRow.png"];
        selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"middleRowSelected.png"];
    }
    ((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = rowBackground;
    ((UIImageView *)cell.selectedBackgroundView).image = selectionBackground;

    //


#endif
```

Let me know if it worked
Cheers!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you only want top and bottom for the whole table rather than for each section.  The first thing that comes to mind is to create an array that is the concatenated contents of array1, array2, and array3.  Then when you do the normal cell configuration in cellForRowAtIndexPath:, compare the element you retrieve using section and row to the first and last elements of your cumulative array.